# Using GetX Bind Stream with Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream, flutter-getx

I'm working with Streams, Firebase Firestore and GetX. I want to Stream data from the database without having to use Stream Builder.. because, I will be needing multiple Streams

So. here's my controller

```
RxList<PostModel> viewPost = RxList<PostModel>([]);

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    viewPost.bindStream(PostService.instance
        .getPostsByUser(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid));
}
```

Here's my getPostByUser function, which a Stream that returns a list of post models

```
Stream<List<PostModel>> getPostsByUser(uid) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("problemPost").orderBy('timestamp', descending: true )
        .where("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map(postListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

This function here takes in a snapshot that comes from getPostByUser, and it then returns a list of post models.

```
List<PostModel> postListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return PostModel(
         commentCount: (doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic>)["commentCount"] ?? '',
        firstName: (doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic>)["firstName"] ?? '',
        id: (doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic> )["id"] ?? '',
        lastName: (doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic> )["lastName"] ?? '',
        likes: (doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic> )["likes"] ?? [],
        problemPost: (doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic> )["problemPost"] ?? 'Why now?',
        profileImageUrl: (doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic> )["profileImageUrl"] ?? '',
        timestamp: (doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic> )["timestamp"] ?? 0,
        type: (doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic> )["type"] ?? 0,
        uid: (doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic> )["uid"] ?? '',
        voteFor: (doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic> )["voteFor"] ?? [],
        voteAgainst: (doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic> )["voteAgainst"] ?? [],

      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

So now, here's the issue.. when I tried using it in a ListView Builder I got an empty list.

```
GetBuilder<ProfileViewController>(
                  init: ProfileViewController(),
                  builder: (r) => ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: r.viewPost.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      final userPost = r.viewPost[index];

                      return Text(userPost.firstName);
                           // the result here was empty
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

Here's also the post model class

```
class PostModel {
  final String commentCount;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String id;
  final List likes;
  final List voteFor;
  final List voteAgainst;
  final String problemPost;
  final String profileImageUrl;
  final int type;
  final Timestamp timestamp;
  final String uid;

  PostModel({
    required this.uid,
    required this.commentCount,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.likes,
    required this.voteFor,
    required this.voteAgainst,
    required this.problemPost,
    required this.profileImageUrl,
    required this.type,
    required this.id,
    required this.timestamp,
  });
```

Comment: I have found getX to be not so good in terms of streams. it could be just my experience of getX and streams but I believe you should also take that into consideration.
You might also wanna take a look at this: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/785

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is not enough to know where is the problem, maybe the stream, or something else, make sure the map in stream does return some value (you can print the length before mapping them).

have you wrapped your code inside a GetX builder?

something like this:

```dart
GetX<PostController>(
  init: PostController(),
  builder: (postList) {
    //return list view builder
  }
)
```

also for safety, don't put the `doc.data() as dynamic`

but you should use `doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic>`

Comment: oh thanks! So, I've just updated the question, wrapping my code in GetBuilder, but it still gives the same empty result..

Comment: Well the list size is 0 so it maybe something wrong with the stream, double check it, see if the Stream return any value